# How to join three tables with intersection?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

need to join three tables with intersections. I have three tables:

Raster data (Sentinel 2 imagery);
Grid table 1.28 x 1.28 km;
OSM landuse table/
Based on the grid I need to extract band values from raster data and then based on the polygon I need to extract land classes from the 3rd table. For that I wrote this query:..

```
WITH raster_data AS (
      SELECT ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,1) band1, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,2) band2,
             ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,3) band3, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,4) band4,
             ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,5) band5, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,6) band6,
             ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,7) band7
      
      FROM raster_grid g , public.t32ulc_entire_tile rast
      WHERE ST_Intersects(rast.rast, g.geom)
     ), 
     raster_bands as
(select  ((band1).geom) as geom, 
        (band1).val as b1, 
        (band2).val as b2,
        (band3).val as b3,
        (band4).val as b4,
        (band5).val as b5,
        (band6).val as b6,
        (band7).val as b7

from raster_data),

classes as (SELECT
    DISTINCT ON (l.gid)
    *, 
    l.fclass,
    round(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(g.geom, ST_MakeValid(l.geom)))::numeric, 2) as area
FROM
    raster_bands g
LEFT JOIN
    public.osm_landuse_test l
ON ST_Intersects(g.geom, l.geom)
ORDER BY l.gid, area desc)

select * from classes cl;
```

But this query is taking too long. What is wrong with this query? Actually, all tables are intersecting with geom columns. If query separately (raster and grid, grid and OSM data) it is working very fast.

```
Subquery Scan on cl  (cost=2410957461187.76..2411183662177.28 rows=4090064 width=543)
  ->  Unique  (cost=2410957461187.76..2411183621276.64 rows=4090064 width=547)
        ->  Sort  (cost=2410957461187.76..2411070541232.20 rows=45232017776 width=547)
              Sort Key: l.gid, (round((st_area(st_intersection(((st_pixelaspolygons(rast.rast, 1, true))).geom, st_makevalid(l.geom), '-1'::double precision)))::numeric, 2)) DESC
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.44..2380689523512.92 rows=45232017776 width=547)
                    ->  ProjectSet  (cost=1.02..88780.54 rows=11059000 width=224)
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.02..14077.00 rows=11059 width=18)
                                ->  Seq Scan on t32ulc_entire_tile rast  (cost=0.00..33.25 rows=2025 width=18)
                                ->  Index Scan using raster_grid_id on raster_grid g  (cost=1.02..6.93 rows=1 width=120)
                                      Index Cond: (geom && (rast.rast)::geometry)
                                      Filter: _st_intersects(geom, rast.rast, NULL::integer)
                    ->  Index Scan using osm_landuse_geom_test on osm_landuse_test l  (cost=0.41..10232.66 rows=409 width=415)
                          Index Cond: (geom && ((st_pixelaspolygons(rast.rast, 1, true))).geom)
                          Filter: st_intersects(((st_pixelaspolygons(rast.rast, 1, true))).geom, geom)
JIT:
  Functions: 36
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN public.osm_landuse_test l ON ST_Intersects(g.geom, l.geom)` -- Very slow.

Comment: @CourserXu any suggestions to speed up?

Comment: Refer to [PostGIS doesn't use spatial index with ST_Intersects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130856/postgis-doesnt-use-spatial-index-with-st-intersects)

Comment: @ManapShymyr the problem might be that `raster_data` is a CTE and therefore has no index on `geom`. Have you tried creating a `TEMPORARY TABLE` from `raster_data` with a gist index?